# Expect4j vs Pexpect: simple example

Tags: java, python, ssh, expect, pexpect

I have Java code that uses [Expect4j](https://code.google.com/p/expect4j/). However, I need to rewrite this code into Python. And so I found [Pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Now, I am not really sure how to use any of these and were wondering if anybody could help me with that.

As I understand, the Java [version](https://nikunjp.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/remote-ssh-using-jsch-with-expect4j/)  usually begins like

```
channel = (ChannelShell) session.openChannel("shell")
Expect4j expect = new Expect4j(channel.getInputStream(), channel.getOutputStream());
channel.connect();
```

How would this code look in Python? I have been looking for a few days now and am not really understanding it. I really haven't tried much because I feel like I'm stuck. For connecting to SSH I am going to use [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) (which I guess solves the very first line of code above)